No Ads Are Showing In Google For A Search Term - Google Ads Help
When I perform a certain search in Google, I don't see any ads on the first few pages.  I would think then, that it shouldn't be too expensive to put an ad on one of those first few pages.  So, I created a campaign, ad group, and keyword, specifically for that purpose.  My current Max. CPC is around a dollar.  I'm not seeing any kind of warning on the campaign, ad group, or keyword.  I'm not sure why my ad is not showing on Google for the keyword.  Can someone tell me why this is happening?
